# Excel Opens a Dead Window After Running a Macro and Closing the Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When I close an Excel workbook after running a macro I get a blank window left over if it's the last workbook I had open. It was working as of a month ago as expected (same as saving and closing manually). I cannot use "application.quit" because I have multiple windows open at once. Can anyone suggest a fix?

I'm using 365 16.0.12527.20612 320bit

```
Sub Update_ADI()  
'  
' Update_ADI Macro  
' This macro will change the date, period (update in macro each month), and change the batch name to default.  
'  
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w  
'  
    Sheets("WebADI").Select  
    Range("F12:L12").Select  
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10/03/2020"  
    Range("F13:L13").Select  
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PER08-21"  
    Range("F14:L14").Select  
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SV IBROBE"  
    Range("F15:L15").Select  
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SV IBROBE"  
    Range("F16:L16").Select  
    ActiveWorkbook.Save  
    ActiveWorkbook.Close  
End Sub
```

Comment: No "fix" here, your code closes your workbook, not Excel. You need to add an `Application.Quit` line.

Comment: The blank window isn't open until the workbook closes. After close the blank window opens. To reiterate, this runs when I have many workbooks open so I cannot use quit. The blank window didn't open for the past 4 years until this month.